# Expand a variable set from an environment variable

Tags: bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BAR=$($FOO)
```

Where the objective is to execute a script with (omitted) arguments.

If I execute the script with:

```
FOO="BAR=1 echo" bash test.sh
```

Then I get an error:

```
test.sh: line 3: BAR=1: command not found
```

I suppose there must be a way of telling bash to treat `$FOO` in my script as if it was `BAR=1 echo` (manually expanding the variable works), but I'm a little bit stuck here. Any ideas?

Comment: can just do :`BAR="$FOO"` in your script and check?

Comment: What do I check? Sorry, I don't understand the comment, the objective is to run the command and get the result back in `FOO`.

Comment: What command do you want to run? `BAR=1` is not a valid command on your system.

Comment: @KamilCuk that in itself is not a command, but `BAR=1 echo` is.

Comment: Maybe you mean to run `env BAR=1 echo`? `echo` is the command, `BAR=1` is variable assignment. Or you mean to write a full bash  parser for the command or call `sh -c 'BAR=1 echo'`? Maybe you want `BAR=$(sh -c "$FOO")`?

Comment: That could be it indeed. I think putting the `env` inside the exported variable works. I have to check that the rest of our scripts (Makefiles...) work properly. But this seems to be the "simple" answer!

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050); what you are trying to do will fail in all but the simplest cases. In this case, pre-command assignments are recognized *before* parameter expansion takes place.

Comment: I agree that it would be better not to rely on this, but hey, legacy code... Been trying to move to a new system in more than a year without much success.

Answer (score 0):

That way works:

```
#!/bin/bash
BAR=$FOO
```

and execute:

```
export FOO="BAR=1 echo" && bash test.sh
```

can be ?

Comment: work here with bash 4.3. I used echo $BAR to see the result